# Is there a way to use a C# script to change the inside html of a tag?

Tags: c#, html, tags

I need to change the contents of an  tag from "Shopping Cart" to "Downloads". Normally this would just be done by changing the html by hand but i don't have access to that. Instead i have access to a small snip of a C# script that runs at the server. Is there anyway to change the contents of the tag through a C# script?

EDIT

Okay here is the code i have to change

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl00_PageHeader1_shoppingCart_anchor" class="navBarButton"
   href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl00$PageHeader1$shoppingCart$anchor','')">
      Shopping Cart</a>
```

And here is what the script header has

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
```

Hopefully this gives some more context, i really just need to know if its possible or not so any help at all would be great

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. If the script generates the page, then you can change it so it generates the page differently. If it doesn't, then you probably can't.

Comment: You need to provide more context. The answers could range from changing it via ASP.NET codebehind to having to use the HTML Agility Pack to parse out a static HTML document.

Comment: Do you know if the tag that you want to change has the attribute `runat="server"`? If it does, then you can modify it on the server-side. Otherwise, the answer is no. You would have to modify it client-side with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***As with other answers, this will depend on what the server side code is actually providing***.

You might be able to output some javascript to locate the control in question, and reset its contents, possibly with something like this...

```
document.getElementById('myTagId').innerHTML = 'Downloads';
```

Without seeing what the HTML is, though, I can't help you much more than that.

Comment: This actually might help a lot, if i can't do it through the c# my next move was to try javascript, if it works ill check your answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use an  control in place of the standard HTML and change the contents of this as and when required;

```
<asp:Literal id="litHeading" runat="server">Shopping Cart</asp:Literal>
```

and in code_behind

```
litHeading.Text = "Downloads";
```